# How to do update operation for show and hide div in mvc5?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i want to do update operation for show and hide div in mvc5 . I will explain my issue with example.

[image]

This is my view. In this view i have one field called **VisitType**. If i clcik the Visit Type as **DirectVisit** the **StartTime** and **EndTime** field will be show(visible) othesewise it will be hide mode.

**My Model (Visistors View Mode)**

```
    public bool VisitType { get; set; } 
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
```

**My View**

```
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="VisitType">
  <div class="form-group">
  <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
  @Html.Label("Visit Type", new { @class = "control-label" })
  <label>
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.VisitType, "true", new { id = "" }) Telephone
  </label>
  <label>
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.VisitType, "false", new { id = "" }) Direct Visit
  </label>
       </div>
     </div>

<div id="StartTime">
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="foem-group">

@Html.Label("Start Time", new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control ", type = "text" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime)
       </div>
      </div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="form-group">
@Html.Label("End Time", new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndTime, new { @class = "form-control ", type = "text" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime)

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**My Jquery code**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#StartTime').hide();
            $('#VisitType input[type="radio"]').change(function () {

                if ($(this).val() === 'false') {
                    $('#StartTime').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('#StartTime').hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

Now what i want is if i put one entry in my application by selecting the VisitType as Direct Visit and enter StartTime and EndTime ans Saved it. Now i want to change the VisitType as Telephone. So i click the Edit button and once it open the view it have to pass the value  to  Visit type radio button and also Start Time and end time time also need to be visible with values.

I passed the value to radio buttons in edit mode. But i donno hoe to visible the StartTime and EndTime in edit mode. I donno  the exact j-query code. This is the issue. Please any one help me to resolve this issue.

**The Code which i tried**

Contrroller Code

```
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid ?id)
    {
        WafeERP_NEWEntities db = new WafeERP_NEWEntities();
        VisitorsViewModel objvisitorsviewmodel = new VisitorsViewModel();
        View_VisitorsForm objviewvisitorsForm = db.View_VisitorsForm.Find(id);
        if (objviewvisitorsForm.VisitType== true)
        {
            objvisitorsviewmodel.VisitType= true;
        }
        else
        {
            objvisitorsviewmodel.VisitType= false;
        }
        ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "DisplayName", objviewvisitorsForm.EmployeeID);
        ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "DisplayName", objviewvisitorsForm.CustomerID);

        objvisitorsviewmodel.VisitingID = objviewvisitorsForm.VisitingID;
        objvisitorsviewmodel.Date = objviewvisitorsForm.VisitingDate;
        objvisitorsviewmodel.VisitType= objvisitorsviewmodel.VisitType;
        return View(objvisitorsviewmodel);
    }
```

This code pass fetch the value from db and pass it to radio button correctly but now i want to show the starttime and endtime field with values once the view got open by clicking edit button. I tried my level best to explain the issue please any one help me to resolve this issue.

Advance thanks..

Comment: Replace `$('#StartTime').hide();` with `if ('@Model.VisitType' == 'true') { $('#StartTime').hide(); )` But `VisitType` should not be typeof `bool` - it should be an `enum` with values (say) `Telephone` and `DirectVisit` - what happen when you decide to add say Skype` in the future)

Comment: we can chat in skype too

Comment: [![enter image description here][2]][2]
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kyXy0.jpg   Stephen i did same as like what you said but it showing error near to model which is shown in that  image

Comment: What is the error message? (you have other issues as well if that's happening). And not related, but remove the pointless `new { type = "text"` }`

Comment: mhm ok i removed  wait i will copy and paste that error here

Comment: [![enter image description here][2]][2]
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qGaV3.jpg see the error stephen

Comment: Then somewhere in your view your have done something silly like use `@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SomeProperty)` - with capital `M` - just always use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty)`

Comment: Also you might need to use `if ('@Model.VisitType' == 'True')` - capital `T` (can't remember if it outputs "true" or "True")

Comment: ok wait i have a check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115359/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-susan).

Comment: Stephen its working i gave True 'T' in capital. may i know the purpose of using Capital T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by first wrapping the elements in a `<div>` so that you can show and hide them all rather than having to select all the associated labels, textboxes and validation message placeholders

```
<div id="date-controls">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartTime)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.STartTime)
    ....
</div>
```

and use css to initially hide them

```
#date-controls {
    display:none;
}
```

then to display them initially if the value of `VisitType` is `true`, add the following script

```
var isVisit = '@Model.ContactMethod';
var dateControls = $('#date-controls');

if (isVisit == 'True') {
    dateControls.show();
}
```

and also modify the script handling the radio buttons to

```
$('#VisitType input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
    var selected = $('#VisitType input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
    if (selected == 'true') {
        dateControls.show();
    } else {
        dateControls.hide();
    }
});
```

Side note: Your `VisitType` property should not be a `bool`. A bool should only be used for a property to which the answer can only be Yes or No, and the answer to *What is the method of contacting us* is not Yes or No, its by Telephone, or by Attending a meeting etc. By using a `bool` it also means that you have no flexibility to add other types in the future (your client might want to offer home visits to incapacitated people, or the option of video conferencing). Instead your property should be a collection or an `enum`.